# Why isnt' sbt giving me the option to choose what to run?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I have a playframework application that uses sbt.

When I am in sbt and type run, it always runs my playframework application.

Inside my project I have a namespace like:

```
package com.example.com.tools

object Seeds extends App {

// code here
}
```

When I type run in sbt:

```
run
```

Shouldn't it give me a list of applications to choose from?

I also tried:  run com.example.tools.Seeds but it says wrong number of args.

sbt version 13.5

Comment: You don't want to pass any args to your main program. correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```scala
> runMain com.example.tools.Seeds
```